# NodeJS & express catch write function of HTTP module using a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am writing an express application using

- NodeJS v8
- express (latest version)

After looking at the [onHeaders](https://github.com/jshttp/on-headers/blob/2e844930550c913c6411250cdf2fed66570477f0/index.js#L24) module and finding out how the module rewrites the HTTP head, I wanted to make use of that function of JavaScript.

I wanted to write a small session system using my SQL server. I am aware of the `session` module from express, but this module is not able to handle the specific tables and customization, I need. 
For convenience reasons I wanted the session to be inserted into the request before the controllers and saved after all controllers finished. (e.g. the writeHead method has been called)

My code in the session looks like:

```
    core = async function(req, res, next) {
        res.writeHead = hijackHead(res.writeHead);         // Hijack the writeHead method to apply our header at the last
    }

    //[...](Omitted code)

    hijackHead = function(writeFunction) {
        let fired = false;

        return function hackedHead(statusCode) {
            if ( fired ) {
                return;
            }

    //[...](Omitted code)

            debug("Session data has changed. Writing");
            sessionManager.storeSessionData(session.identifier, session).then(() => { // Promise taking ~60ms to resolve 
                debug("Finished writing...");
                callMe(); // Current idea of calling the writeHead of the original res 
            });



            let that = this,     // Arguments to apply to the original writeHead
                args = arguments

            function callMe() {
                debug("Finished! Give control to http, statuscode: %i", statusCode);
                writeFunction.apply(that, args);  // Call the original writeHead from the response
                debug("Sent!")
            }
       } // End of hackedHead
    } // End of hijackHead
```

The core function is being passed to express as a middleware.
Additionally `sessionManager.storeSessionData` is a Promise storing data and fulfilling after that, taking ~60ms. The Promise has been testes and works perfectly.
When I now make a request using this Controller, the Node `net` Module returns the error:

```
TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
    at Socket.write (net.js:704:11)
    at ServerResponse._flushOutput (_http_outgoing.js:842:18)
    at ServerResponse._writeRaw (_http_outgoing.js:258:12)
    at ServerResponse._send (_http_outgoing.js:237:15)
    at write_ (_http_outgoing.js:667:15)
    at ServerResponse.end (_http_outgoing.js:751:5)
    at Array.write (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/finalhandler/index.js:297:9)
    at listener (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:169:15)
    at onFinish (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/on-finished/index.js:100:5)
    at callback (/usr/lib/node_modules/express/node_modules/ee-first/index.js:55:10)
```

Since the new function needs about 30ms to react and return the Promise, the function finishes earlier causing Node to crash. 
I already tried blocking the Node loop with a while, timeout or even a recursive function. Neither of them worked.

I tries to simplfy the code as much as possible and I hope that I didn't simplify it too much.

Now I am asking if anybody can help me, how to call the `writeHead` function properly after the Promise has resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The issue with this is, that `net.js` directly responds to those methods when writeHead has finished. Even though the head has not been written, it tries to write the body.
Instead it is possible to catch the `end()`method which will await everything and then close the connection.